# Elegant ways to handle unique IFs

Tags: c#, winforms

Open up to different suggestions. My problem is the following : I have a medium sized text file ( ~100 lines) and need to extract information from specific lines from this configuration file

```
AcquisitionMode=3           --> 3
MovingCalculationLoop=1
MovingCalculationType=0
ReadoutMode=4               --> 4
ReadoutRegisterMode=0
```

For example out of these line I need to know that AcquisitionMode is 3 to write that to another int AcqMode.
Is there a more elegant way than writing 15 if else statements? 
my current is:

```
if (line.Contains("FrameTransferAcquisitionMode")) { LabelTemp2.Text = Regex.Match(line, @"\d+$").Value.ToString(); }
else if (line.Contains("AcquisitionMode")) { LabelTemp1.Text = Regex.Match(line, @"\d+$").Value.ToString(); }
```

ignore the labeltemps, those are for testing purposes only
Thanks

Comment: You can use Dictionary<string, Action<int>> instead If's

Comment: Do you have any control over the format of the text file?  If so, I'd say use XML or JSON, and then use one of the built in libraries to extract the info.

Comment: You can fairly easily parse this to a bunch of key/value pairs, but it's not clear from your question what your end game is.  What are you trying to do with the data once you've read it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a map between the different expected modes and your labels:

```
Dictionary<string,Label> modeMap = new Dictionary<string,Label>()
{
    { "FrameTransferAcquisitionMode", LabelTemp2 },
    { "AcquisitionMode", LabelTemp1 },
};
```

then extract the mode from the line and perform a lookup in the dictionary:

```
string mode = line.Split('=')[0];
Label label;
if(modeMap.TryGetValue(mode, out label))
{
    label.Text = Regex.Match(line, @"\d+$").Value.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var lines = File.ReadLines("settings.ini");
var lookup = lines.ToLookup(l => l.Split('=')[0], l => l.Split('=').ElementAtOrDefault(1));

string sAcquisitionMode = lookup["AcquisitionMode"].FirstOrDefault(); // null if not found
int AcqMode;
int.TryParse(sAcquisitionMode, out AcqMode); // AcqMode is set to 0 if the sting can't be parsed
```

**Update**

Alternative that tries to parse the file as XML

```
var text = File.ReadAllText("settings.ini").Trim().Replace("\r\n", "' ").Replace("=", "='"); // Example: "a=1" to "a='1'"
//text = text.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "='"); // optional if your file has any [sections]  Example: "[a]" to "a=''"
var x = XElement.Parse("<x " + text + "' />");
int AcqMode = (int)x.Attribute("AcquisitionMode"); // in VB.NET this will be Dim AcqMode = Cint(x.@AcquisitionMode)
```